# Combining two world maps

Tags: plotting, legending, geographics

I am trying to combine two world maps with the command "show" and Mathematica indicates an error (see images underneath). Does anyone know what the problem might be and how I can solve it? I am thankful for any help!

The most important codes:

```
data = Map[Rule[Entity["Country", #[[1]]], #[[2]]] &, 
  DataACT1Combination$TMP]

H = 
  GeoBubbleChart[data, 
    BubbleSizes -> {0.02, 0.04}, 
    BubbleScale -> "Diameter", 
    ImageSize -> 1000,ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]




   DevelopedCountries = {Entity["Country", "Albania"], Entity["Country", "Algeria"], Entity["Country", "Argentina"], Entity["Country", "Australia"], Entity["Country", "Austria"], Entity["Country", "Azerbaijan"], Entity["Country", "Bahamas"], Entity["Country", "Bahrain"], Entity["Country", "Barbados"], Entity["Country", "Belarus"], Entity["Country", "Belgium"], Entity["Country", "BosniaHerzegovina"],Entity["Country", "Botswana"], Entity["Country", "Brazil"], Entity["Country", "Brunei"], Entity["Country", "Bulgaria"], Entity["Country", "Canada"], Entity["Country", "Chile"], Entity["Country", "China"], Entity["Country", "Colombia"], Entity["Country", "CostaRica"], Entity["Country", "Croatia"], Entity["Country", "Cuba"], Entity["Country", "Cyprus"], Entity["Country", "CzechRepublic"], Entity["Country", "Denmark"], Entity["Country", "Dominica"], Entity["Country", "DominicanRepublic"],Entity["Country", "Ecuador"], Entity["Country", "Egypt"],Entity["Country", "EquatorialGuinea"], Entity["Country", "Estonia"],Entity["Country", "Finland"], Entity["Country", "France"], Entity["Country", "Gabon"], Entity["Country", "Georgia"], Entity["Country", "Germany"], Entity["Country", "Greece"], Entity["Country", "Hungary"], Entity["Country", "Iceland"], Entity["Country", "Indonesia"], Entity["Country", "Iran"], Entity["Country", "Iraq"], Entity["Country", "Ireland"], Entity["Country", "Israel"], Entity["Country", "Italy"], Entity["Country", "Japan"], Entity["Country", "Jordan"], Entity["Country", "Kazakhstan"], Entity["Country", "SouthKorea"], Entity["Country", "Kuwait"], Entity["Country", "Latvia"], Entity["Country", "Lebanon"], Entity["Country", "Liechtenstein"], Entity["Country", "Lithuania"], Entity["Country", "Luxembourg"], Entity["Country", "Macedonia"], Entity["Country", "Malaysia"], Entity["Country", "Maldives"], Entity["Country", "Malta"], Entity["Country", "Mauritius"], Entity["Country", "Mexico"], Entity["Country", "Mongolia"], Entity["Country", "Montenegro"], Entity["Country", "Namibia"], Entity["Country", "Netherlands"], Entity["Country", "NewZealand"], Entity["Country", "Norway"], Entity["Country", "Oman"], Entity["Country", "Panama"], Entity["Country", "Peru"], Entity["Country", "Poland"], Entity["Country", "Portugal"], Entity["Country", "Qatar"], Entity["Country", "Romania"], Entity["Country", "Russia"], Entity["Country", "SaintLucia"], Entity["Country", "SaintVincentGrenadines"], Entity["Country", "SaudiArabia"], Entity["Country", "Serbia"], Entity["Country", "Seychelles"], Entity["Country", "Singapore"], Entity["Country", "Slovakia"], Entity["Country", "Slovenia"], Entity["Country", "SouthAfrica"], Entity["Country", "SouthSudan"], Entity["Country", "Spain"], Entity["Country", "Sudan"], Entity["Country", "Suriname"], Entity["Country", "Sweden"], Entity["Country", "Syria"], Entity["Country", "Tanzania"], Entity["Country", "TrinidadTobago"], Entity["Country", "Tunisia"], Entity["Country", "Turkey"], Entity["Country", "Turkmenistan"], Entity["Country", "UnitedArabEmirates"], Entity["Country", "UnitedKingdom"], Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"], Entity["Country", "Uruguay"], Entity["Country", "Venezuela"]}




DevelopingCountries = {Entity["Country", "Afghanistan"], Entity["Country", "Angola"], Entity["Country", "Armenia"], Entity["Country", "Benin"], Entity["Country", "Bhutan"], Entity["Country", "Bolivia"], Entity["Country", "BurkinaFaso"], Entity["Country", "Burundi"], Entity["Country", "CapeVerde"], Entity["Country", "Cambodia"], Entity["Country", "Cameroon"], Entity["Country", "CentralAfricanRepublic"], Entity["Country", "Chad"], Entity["Country", "Comoros"], Entity["Country", "DemocraticRepublicCongo"], Entity["Country", "RepublicCongo"], Entity["Country", "IvoryCoast"],Entity["Country", "Djibouti"], Entity["Country", "ElSalvador"], Entity["Country", "Eritrea"], Entity["Country", "Swaziland"], Entity["Country", "Ethiopia"], Entity["Country", "Fiji"], Entity["Country", "Gambia"], Entity["Country", "Ghana"], Entity["Country", "Guatemala"], Entity["Country", "Guinea"], Entity["Country", "GuineaBissau"], Entity["Country", "Guyana"], Entity["Country", "Haiti"], Entity["Country", "Honduras"], Entity["Country", "India"], Entity["Country", "Jamaica"], Entity["Country", "Kenya"], Entity["Country", "Kiribati"], Entity["Country", "Kosovo"], Entity["Country", "Kyrgyzstan"], Entity["Country", "Laos"], Entity["Country", "Lesotho"], Entity["Country", "Liberia"], Entity["Country", "Libya"], Entity["Country", "Madagascar"], Entity["Country", "Malawi"], Entity["Country", "Mali"], Entity["Country", "Mauritania"], Entity["Country", "Micronesia"], Entity["Country", "Moldova"], Entity["Country", "Morocco"], Entity["Country", "Mozambique"], Entity["Country", "Myanmar"], Entity["Country", "Nepal"], Entity["Country", "Nicaragua"], Entity["Country", "Niger"], Entity["Country", "Nigeria"], Entity["Country", "Pakistan"], Entity["Country", "PapuaNewGuinea"], Entity["Country", "Paraguay"], Entity["Country", "Philippines"], Entity["Country", "Rwanda"], Entity["Country", "Samoa"], Entity["Country", "SaoTomePrincipe"], Entity["Country", "Senegal"], Entity["Country", "SierraLeone"], Entity["Country", "SolomonIslands"], Entity["Country", "SriLanka"], Entity["Country", "Taiwan"], Entity["Country", "Tajikistan"], Entity["Country", "EastTimor"], Entity["Country", "Togo"], Entity["Country", "Tonga"], Entity["Country", "Uganda"], Entity["Country", "Ukraine"], Entity["Country", "Uzbekistan"], Entity["Country", "Vanuatu"], Entity["Country", "Vietnam"], Entity["Country", "Yemen"], Entity["Country", "Zambia"], Entity["Country", "Zimbabwe"]}

Color$Developed = Blue
Color$Developing = Red

FinalPlotCountries =
   Labeled[
     GeoRegionValuePlot[
       Join[
         Map[Rule[#, Color$Developed] &, DevelopedCountries], 
         Map[Rule[#, Color$Developing] &, DevelopingCountries]], 
       GeoLabels -> False, 
       LabelStyle -> {8, Bold, Italic}, 
       ImageSize -> 1000, 
       GeoRange -> "World", 
       AspectRatio -> 1/1.5, 
       Epilog -> 
         Inset[
           SwatchLegend[
             {Blue, Red}, {"developed    ",  "developing    "}, 
             LegendLayout -> "Row"],
           Scaled[{0.5, 0.03}]]] // Framed, 
     Style["Development Status of Countries", 25, FontFamily -> "Times"],
     Top]

Show [FinalPlotCountries, H]
```

[image: Map1]
[image: Map2]

[image: Error message]

Comment: Sorry, I am new here! Posted the codes above now

Comment: You are setting `GeoBubbleChart` to `GeoBubbleChart`, use a different name. Can you provide `data` so we can reproduce your result. What is `DevelopedCountries` and `Color$Developed` and `Color$Developing`?

Comment: `data`, `Color$Developed` and `DevelopedCountries` are not defined in your code, so it doesn't evaluate properly and we can't see what your problem is. Also, in your 1st chart, a comma is missing after `ImageSize -> 100`

Comment: Thank you for the answers! As I am working on a large dataset it is hard for me to include every code used. But I added `data`, (wich is a combination ( `DataACT1Combination$TMP`) of the world happiness score (provided in the dataset) and a list of the countries, also provided in the dataset),   `Color$Developed`, `Color$Developing`, `DevelopingCountries` and `DevelopedCountries`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
fiftycountries = RandomSample[EntityList["Country"], 50];
selected = RandomSample[fiftycountries, 30];
data = # -> #[ "Population"] & /@ selected;
others = Complement[fiftycountries, selected];
```

Easiest way to show the two plots together is to use the graphics primitives produced by `GeoBubbleChart` as `Epilog` in `GeoRegionValuePlot`:

```
gbc = GeoBubbleChart[data, BubbleSizes -> {0.02, 0.04}, 
   BubbleScale -> "Diameter", 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", GeoRange -> "World", 
   GeoBackground -> None];


fpc = Labeled[GeoRegionValuePlot[
    Join[Map[Rule[#, Opacity[.5, Red]] &, selected], 
     Map[Rule[#, Blue] &, others]], GeoLabels -> False, 
    LabelStyle -> {8, Bold, Italic}, ImageSize -> 900, 
    GeoRange -> "World", 
    Epilog -> {gbc[[1, 1]], 
      Inset[SwatchLegend[{Red, Blue}, {"selected    ", "others    "}, 
        LegendLayout -> "Row"], Scaled[{0.5, 0.03}]]}] // Framed, 
  Style["Development Status of Countries", 25, FontFamily -> "Times"], Top]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `Show` using the `GeoGraphics` object in your `FinalPlotCountries` (which is the part `FinalPlotCountries[[1,1]]`) add `Framed` and `Labeled` later:

```
Labeled[Framed@Show[FinalPlotCountries[[1, 1]], gbc], 
 Style["Development Status of Countries", 25, FontFamily -> "Times"], Top]
```

[image]

but this approach requires further work to clean up white paddings.

***Why your code does not work?***

`Show` expects objects with head `Graphics` (or `GeoGraphics`) as arguments. `fpc` is an object with `Head` `Labeled` (not `GeoGraphics`).

A simpler example that shows the same issue:

```
plot1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red];
plot2 = Labeled[Framed@Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Blue], 
   Style["label", 20], Top];
Show[plot2, plot1]
```

[image]

The fix is the same: Either use the graphics primitives of `plot1` (i.e., `plot1[[1]]`) as `Epilog` in the second plot:

```
Labeled[Framed@
  Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
   Epilog -> plot1[[1]]], Style["label", 20], Top]
```

or use `Show[plot2[[1, 1]], plot1]` and add the frame and labels later:

```
Labeled[Framed @ Show[plot2[[1, 1]], plot1], Style["label", 20], Top]
```

Both approaches give

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! Do you also happen to know how to add a second legend to the right of the map `fpc` that shows each bubble size and respective color (from the map) with the respective number and the legend title "Happiness scores"? I can unfortunately not manage

Comment: @Faye, normally, if  `plot1` and `plot2` are produced with the `PlotLegends` (or `ChartLegends`) option `Show[plot1,plot2]` combines the legends of the two plots. But with the combination of  `GeoBubbleChart` (with the option `ChartLegends` ) and GeoRegionValuePlot` (with the option `PlotLegends`), obvious things i tried did not work. You might want to post this as a new question with a simplified example.